# How to make image elements scale with window instead of repositioning

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a project, where I have 4 images together in the middle of the window, laid out like this:

```
12
34
```

I want the images to all scale up and down with the window, but maintain their position.

Right now, I have them all in a div called Center:

```
<div style="max-width:1200px;" id="centerArrows">        
    <img src="images/homePage/arrowUL.png" style="position: relative; top: -100px; float:left;"  />
    <img src="images/homePage/arrowUR.png" style="position: relative; left: 40px; top: -95px;" />    
    <img src="images/homePage/arrowDL.png" style="position: relative; left: -35px; top: -80px;" />
    <img src="images/homePage/arrowDR.png" style="position: relative; left: 670px; top: -510px;" />
</div>
```

with this CSS:

```
#centerArrows {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;    
    margin-bottom: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;   
    width: auto;        
}
img {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LDt8P/

```
html , body , #centerArrows{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#centerArrows{
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

---

Fiddle in response to the comment to restrict the image from spreading out to 4 lines:

http://jsfiddle.net/LDt8P/1/

---

*Solution with JQuery* to make the image smaller to fit the width of the window when the window width is smaller that a specific width:

http://jsfiddle.net/LDt8P/3/

Comment: This solves the issue with getting the image to remain centered, but when the window gets smaller than the images, I'd like the images to retain their position and scale down, instead of moving onto a new line.

Comment: It isnt moving into a new line.And what do you mean by scale down?Is it hat the images should get smaller

Comment: So, when the window scales down past the borders of the table, the images spread out to 4 lines, like this: http://imgur.com/9S4lWLw

Instead, I'd like to find a way for the 4 images to resize with the window, so they still look the same, just smaller.

Comment: I am working on it .I will post your required code later @Ryan

Comment: @Ryan the former part of the issue you mentioned is solved but the latter part will require JQuery/Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
var initialWidth = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('img').each(function(){
        var img         = $(this),
            pos         = img.data('pos') || $(this).offset(),
            imgWidth    = img.data('width') || img.width(),
            ratio       = $(window).width() / initialWidth,
            newImgWidth = imgWidth * ratio,
            newImgLeft  = pos * ratio;
        img.css({
                width: newImgWidth + 'px',
                left: newImgLeft + 'px'
            });
    });
}).resize();
```

Here is a simple jQuery implementation. In this case you have to use position: fixed or position: absolute (in this case the elements relative parent should be the body.

The code is untested... (sorry, i don't really have time now)