# Getting image to scale/center dynamically with window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

On a webpage, I have 5 image links, laid out like the 5 side of a dice. The 4 corners all come together in the middle, and the center image lays on top (it's going to be a "home" button).

I already managed to get the 4 corner images to stay together while remaining centered and scaling down with the window (as seen [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966794/how-to-make-image-elements-scale-with-window-instead-of-repositioning)), but the problem I'm having now is getting my top layer image to do the same thing.

```
<script>
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width()<=1346) {
            $('.rowdiv').find('img').css({ 'width': '100%' });
        }
        else {
            $('.rowdiv').find('img').css({ 'width': '673px' });
        }
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width()<=1346) {
            $('.rowdiv2').find('img').css({ 'width': '100%' });
        }
        else {
            $('.rowdiv2').find('img').css({ 'width': '220px' });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Is the fact that I have 2 different resize functions negating my second one?

Comment: Can you share more codes or a jsfiddle link?

Comment: Sure thing. Give me a minute; my code is kind of a mess...

Comment: It'd be much better to use CSS media queries for this.

Comment: All right, I moved all my code into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TLhP9/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS media queries to achieve this quite easily. For example:

```
.rowdiv img { width: 673px; }
.rowdiv2 img { width: 220px; }

@media (max-width: 1346px) {
    .rowdiv img,
    .rowdiv2 img { width: 100%; }
}
```

Please see this [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TLhP9/1/), or the [full screen result](http://jsfiddle.net/TLhP9/1/embedded/result/).

Comment: This sort of works. I put this code into my jsfiddle, but it's not behaving quite right. I'd like it to start scaling down as soon as the window resizes, not just when the image won't fit in the bounds of the window anymore. Is there a way to accomplish this with padding in CSS?

Comment: Okay, I think I figured it out; I just added a left:30%; and a right:30%; to .rowdiv2.

Except, when I run the jsfiddle full-screen result, everything scales up to fill the window and I have no idea why. Thoughts?

http://jsfiddle.net/TLhP9/2/

Comment: It's forcing the `100%` rule, likely because your window is < 1346px.